# What's a clean way to test that no callbacks are registered on an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an object which for reasons of data scaling, needs to call `Object.where(x=y).delete_all`. Using `destroy_all` is too time consuming.

However as a result of that I want to enforce that no dev accidentally registers an `after_destroy` callback or even a `dependent: destroy` relationship because they'll both be ignored during the `delete_all` process.

What would be the best way in RSpec to test that `after_destroy` a model receives NO callbacks?

I'd like to achieve something along these lines:

```
it "should not have any registered after_destroy callbacks" do
  o = MyObject.new
  o.destroy
  expect(o).to_not have_received('*')
end
```

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that approach is doomed: many methods internal to Active Record are called during a call to `destroy`, and you'd have to sort those out from your methods, or ones defined by callbacks (the bad methods won't necessarily have an obvious name, eg if they use the block form of before/after destroy).

You can however directly inspect the set of callbacks:

```
MyObject._destroy_callbacks
```

and check whether it is empty.

You can check what options have been set on associations more explicitly:

```
MyObject.reflect_on_all_associations.any? {|reflection| reflection.options[:dependent] == :destroy}
```

but these are implemented using callbacks so should show up in `_destroy_callbacks`

Comment: Oh well that's perfect - exactly what I needed, thank you. Do you also happen to know if there's a way to test that it does *not* have `dependent:destroy` on associations?

Comment: They should show up in the list of callbacks, but you walk the list of associations as I have added to the answer